# How to build an N-Gram relationship in Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, frontend, n-gram

I am new to Elasticsearch, and I am looking to build a Front-End app which has a list of proverbs. As the user browses these proverbs, I want them to find related N-Gram proverbs, or analytic proverbs from the Proverb DB. For example when clicking on

"A watched pot never boils" would bring the following suggestions:

- **1-Gram suggestion:**
  *"Two pees in a pot"*
- **2-Gram suggestion:**
  *"A Watched pot tastes bitter"*
- **Analytical suggestion:**    *"Too many cooks spoil the broth"*

Is there a way to do that in ES, or do I need to build my own logic ?

Comment: The 1-gram and 2-gram suggestions are easy, but I don't get the analytical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1-gram suggestion works out of the box and the 2-gram suggestions can easily be achieved with `shingle`.

Here is an attempt

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "2-grams": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "shingles"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "shingles": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 2,
          "output_unigrams": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "fields": {
          "2gram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "2-grams"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next index some documents:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "text": "Two pees in a pot"
}

PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "text": "A Watched pot tastes bitter"
}
```

Finally, you can search for 1-gram suggestions using the following query and you'll get both documents in the response:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "A watched pot never boils"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also search for 2-gram suggestions using the following query and only the second document will come up:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text.2gram": "A watched pot never boils"
    }
  }
}
```

PS: Not sure how the "analytical" suggestion works, though, feel free  to provide more insights, and I'll update.

Comment: Hi Val, I had technical issues and only just got around to this. I will look into it. It says my bounty expires, I don't know what that entails. 

With regards to the analytics, I meant to say that a pots cooks and broth are all Culinary concepts.

Comment: An expiring bounty means that you [lost your points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326181/what-happens-when-a-bounty-expires) without attributing them to someone else, which means you might get less attention on your next questions ;-) No worries, let me know how it goes when you have time